# How to sort a file with string lines by the number of a specific symbol in the line?

Tags: mac, command-line, terminal, regex, plaintext

Say I have a large plaintext file with a string on every line. The string only consists of alphabetical characters, except for underscores `_`, which divide the strings in syllables.

I want to sort the text file by the amount underscores in the string. Bonus points for putting every group of X underscores in their own file.

Example:

```
hel_lo
hi
su_per_u_ser
o_ver_flow
```

would sort into:

```
hi
hel_lo
o_ver_flow
su_per_u_ser
```

I've tried doing this with regex, but I've yet to find a proper way of counting the underscores (regex confuses me thoroughly).

Anyone know how I could handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python makes this easy...

```
open('out.txt', 'w').write('\n'.join(sorted(open('in.txt'), key=lambda x: x.count('_'))))
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Removed the \n to get rid of the superfluous empty line. And had to figure out how to run Python scripts as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Simple code in `awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN   { FS = "_" }        # field separator = syllable separator
        {                   # for each input line
            if(NF > 0)      # if number of syllables > 0
                print $0 > "syllable-"NF".txt"  # print the line to a file
        }
```

Put the script into a file and then `chmod a+x` the file. The input can come from `stdin` or from a file specified as a parameter to the script.

The output will be sorted in files named `syllable-x.txt` where `x` is the number of syllables.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler: a bash one-liner:

```
 cat testfile | while read line; do echo $line >> srt$(echo $line | fgrep -o _ | wc -l).txt ; done
```

Output will appear in files called srtN.txt, where N is the number of occurrences of the underscore character in the line.